# How to skip karma test in jhipster v4.13.0

Tags: jhipster

I am using jhipster 4.13.0. Anything is ok until I create production package: 
./mvnw -Pprod package

It is always failed in karma test. How can I skip the karma test, because I don't need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your `package.json` and remove call to karma from `"test": "yarn run lint && karma start src/test/javascript/karma.conf.js"`

Answer (score 2):

Try running this command in your terminal:

```
./mvnw -Pprod package -DskipTests
```